# Prove two triangular properties about set distances.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-sets

In particular, I need to prove the following: $d(A_1,B_1)+d(A_2,B_2)\geq d(A_1\cup A_2,B_1\cup B_2)$ and $d(A_1,B_1)+d(A_2,B_2)\geq d(A_1\cap A_2,B_1\cap B_2)$.

Reading from Baby Rudin, it seems these require knowing properties of symmetric differences, namely $S(A_1,B_1) \cup S(A_2,B_2) \text{ contains }
 S(A_1\cup A_2,B_1\cup B_2),
S(A_1\cap A_2,B_1\cap B_2), \text{ and }S(A_1\setminus A_2,B_1\setminus B_2)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To get the best answers and a good reception to your question, you should add some more detail about the problem and your attempts at solving it.

Comment: What is your definition of $d(A,B)$? Are these subsets of a metric space? Usually, $d(A,B) = \text{inf}\{d(a,b)\;|\;a \in A,\; b \in B\}.$

Comment: $d(A,B)= \mu^*((,))$, where $\mu^*$ is the outer measure, and $S$ is the symmetric difference of A and B.

Comment: are the sets in question measurable? What does $d(S)$ denote for a set $S$?

Comment: Both sets are measurable, and for this, $d$ is only defined for two sets. A and B are both in $\mathbb{R}^p$

Comment: I see, was there a typo when you write $d(A_1 \cup A_2)$ then?

Comment: Whoops: correct to $d(A_1,B_1)+d(A_2,B_2)\geq d(A_1\cup A_2,B_1\cup B_2)$ and $d(A_1,B_1)+d(A_2,B_2)\geq d(A_1\cap A_2,B_1\cap B_2)$

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of an outer measure(particularly monotonicity and subadditivity), it suffices to show that $$S(A_1 \cup A_2, B_1 \cup B_2) \subseteq S(A_1, B_1) \cup S(A_2, B_2).$$

If $x \in S(A_1 \cup A_2, B_1 \cup B_2)$, then WLOG we can assume $x \in (A_1 \cup A_2) \setminus (B_1 \cup B_2)$. Then $x \in A_1$ or $x \in A_2$ so again we can ssume WLOG that $x \in A_1$. Since $x \in A_1$ and $x \notin B_1 \cup B_2$ so $x \notin B_1$. Hence. $x \in A_1 \setminus B_1 \subseteq S(A_1,B_1). $

The other inequality is very similar. No assumption of measurability is necessary.

Comment: Does this hold if A and B are disjoint? That's where I got stuck here...

Comment: Yes, unless I assumed that they had nonempty intersection somewhere. I don't think I did, though.